# where can i find the file and android write in JNI

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, fopen

I wirte a test demo for ffmpeg, read a `flac` file and decoder it to a new `pcm` file.

after done the work, i could not find the output file.

so I open the output file with a new `FILE` pointer, and open is ok, does anybody give any tips, thanks.

```
static int decode_packet(int *got_frame, int cached)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int decoded = pkt.size;

    *got_frame = 0;

    if (pkt.stream_index == audio_stream_idx) {
        /* decode audio frame */
        ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(audio_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOG("Error decoding audio frame (%s)\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }

        decoded = FFMIN(ret, pkt.size);

        if (*got_frame) {
            LOG("frame->format: %d", frame->format);
            size_t unpadded_linesize = frame->nb_samples * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16/*frame->format*/);
            LOG("audio_frame%s n:%d nb_samples:%d pts:%s\n", cached ? "(cached)" : "", audio_frame_count++, frame->nb_samples,
                   av_ts2timestr(frame->pts, &audio_dec_ctx->time_base));

            fwrite(frame->extended_data[0], 1, unpadded_linesize, audio_dst_file);
        }
    }

    if (*got_frame && api_mode == API_MODE_NEW_API_REF_COUNT)
        av_frame_unref(frame);

    return decoded;
}

    // as convient i write the abspath `/storage/emulated/0` which i got by rountine Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
    const char *src_filename = "/storage/emulated/0/pyghlkn.flac";
    const char *audio_dst_filename = "/storage/emulated/0/test.pcm";

    FILE *audio_dst_file = NULL;
    FILE *audio_dump = NULL;

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_cn_com_longmaster_ffmpeg_encoder
      (JNIEnv *, jobject)
      {
          //......
            /* read frames from the file */
            while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
                AVPacket orig_pkt = pkt;
                do {
                    ret = decode_packet(&got_frame, 0);
                    LOG("write decode_packet... pkt.size: %d ", pkt.size);
                    if (ret < 0)
                        break;
                    pkt.data += ret;
                    pkt.size -= ret;
                } while (pkt.size > 0);
                av_free_packet(&orig_pkt);
            }

            /* flush cached frames */
            pkt.data = NULL;
            pkt.size = 0;
            do {
                decode_packet(&got_frame, 1);
                LOG("flush cached frames");
            } while (got_frame);


            if (audio_dump)
            {
                LOG("default audio_dump ready...");
            }
            else
            {
                LOG("default audio_dump not ready...");
            }

            audio_dump = fopen(audio_dst_filename, "rb");
            if (audio_dump) {
                LOG("open pcm file ok...");
            } else {
                LOG("open pcm file fail...");
            }

            avcodec_close(audio_dec_ctx);
            avformat_close_input(&fmt_ctx);
            if (audio_dst_file) {
                fclose(audio_dst_file);
            }

            av_frame_free(&frame);

            return ;

      }
```

Comment: *I could not find the output file* - how did you look for it? Did you try `adb shell`?

Comment: Also, it would probably be a better idea to get the external storage path (or whereever it is that you want to store the file) through the Android APIs and pass the path to your native code, instead of using a hardcoded path like `/storage/emulated/0`.

Comment: I finally got the file by the 3rd part APP, and copy it to a new Dir, then use the phone as a USB storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the hard coded path you should use `File dirBase = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // Root directory of SD card` in the java part of your app and pass it on to your C program. 
This path could be e.g. `/storage/sdcard` depending on the vendor of your andorid phone. Useing the function will always give you the correct path.